# how to set log out button at right-corner in my website using html

Tags: javascript, css

I am having a project in which I want to show one log out button at the right-corner of my website.

I am using following code which doesn't work properly.

```
<form align="right" name="form1" method="post" action="log_out.php">
  <label>
  <input name="submit2" type="submit" id="submit2" value="log out">
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: create a div at right corner and place your form there

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Qj87u/4/

Comment: ok.. thank you.. I got solution

Comment: But,In my project I have to show this in many web pages. so, is there any way to use external css file ?

Comment: Yes you can use external css file.just create .css file and give reference where you want to use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it using css as below:

Css:

```
.logoutLblPos{

   position:fixed;
   right:10px;
   top:5px;
}
```

//html

```
<form align="right" name="form1" method="post" action="log_out.php">
  <label class="logoutLblPos">
  <input name="submit2" type="submit" id="submit2" value="log out">
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

wrap your code inside a dive like shown below

```
<div style="float:right">
<form align="right" name="form1" method="post" action="log_out.php">
  <label class="logoutLblPos">
  <input name="submit2" type="submit" id="submit2" value="log out">
  </label>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. select menu with Guest Name and Logout Options and you could increase the number of options based upon your requirement.  , with HTML and Jquery.

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" style='height:50px'>
<select id=logoutmenu  class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-     btn-icon-notext ui-btn-up-a" data-inline='true' onChange=$.RequiredFunction();name="divlogout" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-native-menu="false">
<option value = "blank"></option>
<option id="_optionGuest"> Guest Name </option>
<option id="_logout">Logout</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```